# What property do I need to add to a div in order to hide it for AdBlock Users?

Tags: html, ads, adblock

Complicated title, but that's really all I want to know. I have plenty of Adblock Users on my website and I want to optimize it for them.

So what kind of class (for example) property do I have to add to ad container divs in order to make them invisible to Adblock users?

You see, what I am trying to do is to make a div seem like an advertisement so Adblock hides it.

Edit: A solution I know of would be detecing Adblock per Javascript and then hiding my div according to that. But I want the visitor's adblock hide the div itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use `.banner-adv` class. Using id is not best solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Experimented a bit and found a solution:

```
<div id="adright"><!-- Ad Content --></div>
```

will get hidden by default by all visitors which use Adblock.

Edit: I can only accept my own reply as an answer in 2 days? Oh come on, stackoverflow. I thought you were better than this!